# The MainWindow shown manually raises error on running application in WPF Blazor

Tags: c#, wpf, blazor-hybrid

Considering the sample code below:

Counter.razor:

```
<h1>Counter</h1>
<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBlazor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:blazor="clr-namespace:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfBlazor"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <blazor:BlazorWebView Name="webView" HostPage="wwwroot\index.html" Services="{DynamicResource services}">
        <blazor:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <blazor:RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Counter}" />
        </blazor:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </blazor:BlazorWebView>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddWpfBlazorWebView();
        Resources.Add("services", serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider());
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfBlazor
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            var app = new App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            var window = new MainWindow();
            window.Show();
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

It raises the following error on `app.Run()`:

"EnsureCoreWebView2Async cannot be used before the application's event loop has started running."

It works if I do it in this way, but I can't, since it's a sample code, and in the real situation I need to separate instantiation and showing the window from the app.Run():

```
var window = new MainWindow();
app.Run(window);
```

I have tried calling the `await window.webView.WebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);` in app startup and window loaded but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...and in the real situation I need to separate instantiation and showing the window from the app.Run():

You should still start the app before showing the window. Call the `Run` method of the `App` in your `Main` method and then override the `OnStartup` method of the `App` class to customize the initialization of the window:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    App application = new App();
    application.Run();
}

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var window = new MainWindow();
    window.Show();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's right to limit showing the main window to the application's startup method. It can be a bug regarding the Blazor Hybrid!

Comment: @Mahdi: The "bug" is in your code.